# Problema com Trigger Após Update com Update interno em Mysql

Tags: mysql, sql-update, trigger

Estou criando uma trigger no mysql, a trigger é criada porém quando vou dar update na flag para testar o mysql me retorna este erro

```
ERROR 1442 (HY000): Can't update table 'aux_Batelada' 
in stored function/trigger because it 
is already used by statement which invoked this stored function/trigger.
```

Se alguém puder ajudar. Segue o sql da trigger:

```
DELIMITER $$

CREATE TRIGGER Data_entrada AFTER UPDATE ON scadabr.aux_Batelada FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
if OLD.flag_entrada=0 AND NEW.flag_entrada=1 THEN
    UPDATE scadabr.aux_Batelada SET dtEntrada=NOW() where idBatelada = 0;
end if;
if NEW.flag_final=1 then
    INSERT INTO `scadabr`.`Batelada` (`dtEntrada`, `QTCerragem`, `QTKnor`, `QTCinzas`, `QTRest`, `QTPodas`, `QTPalha`, `VLTempMax`, `VLPesoTotal`,  `VLTempRetirada`,`QtSuper`,`QtComplex`) VALUES (NEW.dtEntrada, NEW.QTCerragem, NEW.QTKnor, NEW.QTCinzas, NEW.QTRest, NEW.QTPodas, NEW.QTPalha, NEW.VLTempMax, NEW.VLPesoTotal, NEW.QtSuper, NEW.QtComplex);
end if; 
END$$

DELIMITER ;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Boa tarde.

Você não pode executar um update na mesma tabela que está criando a `trigger` isso pode fazer sua tabela entrar em `loop`.

Sendo assim uma alternativa é alterar quando a `trigger` é acionada de `AFTER` para `BEFORE`.

Aí você consegue manipular como vai ficar os dados usando o `NEW.`

```
DELIMITER $$

DROP TRIGGER IF EXISTS Data_entrada;
DELIMITER |
CREATE TRIGGER Data_entrada BEFORE UPDATE ON scadabr.aux_Batelada FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN

if OLD.flag_entrada=0 AND NEW.flag_entrada=1 THEN
    SET NEW.dtEntrada = NOW();
end if;

if NEW.flag_final=1 then
    INSERT INTO `scadabr`.`Batelada` (`dtEntrada`, `QTCerragem`, `QTKnor`, `QTCinzas`, `QTRest`, `QTPodas`, `QTPalha`, `VLTempMax`, `VLPesoTotal`,  `VLTempRetirada`,`QtSuper`,`QtComplex`) VALUES (NEW.dtEntrada, NEW.QTCerragem, NEW.QTKnor, NEW.QTCinzas, NEW.QTRest, NEW.QTPodas, NEW.QTPalha, NEW.VLTempMax, NEW.VLPesoTotal, NEW.QtSuper, NEW.QtComplex);
end if; 

END
|
DELIMITER ;
```